# Is it possible to add content to the body of a webpage with a second http request from the server

Tags: sockets, http

I would like to create a webserver which sends the content he fetched from a socket server to a browser client. For this I have to fetch a char from the socket server and send it directly to the client (Webbrowser). I am sending the html body using the following headers:

```cpp
html = "hello world\r\n";
headers << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        << "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        << "Content-Length: " << html.length() << "\r\n"
        << "Connection: close\r\n"
        << "Server: CPi\r\n\r\n"
        << html; // the body of the request
server.sendMessage(client, headers.str());
```

but I would like to keep the connection alive and add something to the body with a second request like this:

```cpp
html1 = "hello \r\n"
headers << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        << "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        << "Content-Length: " << html1.length() << "\r\n" // "hello " has 6 chars
        //<< "Connection: close\r\n" keep the connection alive
        << "Server: CPi\r\n\r\n"
        << html1; // !! send only the first part
server.sendMessage(client, headers.str());

headers.str(""); // clear header data

html2 = "world\r\n";
headers << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        << "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
        << "Content-Length: " << html2.length() << "\r\n"
        << "Connection: close\r\n" // close the connection because the body is complete
        << "Server: CPi\r\n\r\n"
        << html2; // !! append the second part to the body
server.sendMessage(client, headers.str());
```

But it seems not to work. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> But it seems not to work.

HTTP is a protocol where one request has one response. You are trying to send two responses for a single request and the client will simply not expect the second response. This means it will be either ignored or it erroneously will be taken as the response to another request the client is sending on the same TCP connection.

> Is there a way to do it?

It is not fully clear to me what you are trying to achieve with this at the end.
But if your problem is that you don't have the full response at once and that you want to send it to the client in pieces you can use for example [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) of the body.

Comment: AJAX is another option. Make the HTML of the first response contain a script that triggers a second request to fetch the remaining data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: This does not really fit the *"...and add something to the body..."* part in the question. It might or might not fit the actual problem though the OP is trying to solve - unfortunately this problem is unknown.

Comment: "*This does not really fit the "...and add something to the body..." part in the question.*" - It can, if the script in the first HTML response incorporates the new HTML into the existing browser content. AJAX is good for that. It is commonly used for server-side pushing of updated content

Comment: @RemyLebeau: like I said: it might fit the actual although unknown problem the OP is trying to solve. For now I've interpreted the question as the OP trying to add more data to the original response, i.e. without the client issuing a new request. But this might even be the wrong way Y to solve the real problem X inside this [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).